# Correct way of quoting command substitution

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I have simple bash script which only outputs the filenames that are given to the script as positional arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Say I have files with spaces (say "f 1" and "f 2"). I can call the script with a wildcard and get the expected output:

```
$ ./script f*
> f 1
> f 2
```

But if I use command substitution it doesn't work:

```
$ ./script $(echo f*)
> f
> 1
> f
> 2
```

How can I get the quoting right when my command substition outputs multiple filenames with spaces?

Edit: What I ultimatively want is to pass filenames to a script (that is slightly more elaborate than just echoing their names) in a random order, e.g. something like that:

```
./script $(ls f* | shuf)
```

Comment: Is your example just to demonstrate or are you actually trying to echo a glob? What your asking for isn't directly possible, but there are usually ways to work around the limitation depending on what you're really trying to do.

Comment: `$(echo f*)` is split into words based on `IFS`; quoting it like `"$(echo f*)"` would convert the output into a single argument. What exactly is it you're trying to do – do you have an array of files somewhere that you want to pass to `script`, or to you pass around a glob? There probably are ways to convert your glob into an array and then use that, but I'd need a little more context.

Comment: I'm mostly asking because the solution to the problem as presented is "just use the glob".

Comment: Ah, okay, the additional info helps.

Comment: I edited my question. Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: does `bash script $(echo "f*") ` do what you want?

Comment: Command substations produce *a* string, not a series of values. A string containing spaces is in no way equivalent to a list of strings separated by spaces. `shuf` produces, in some sense, a single linefeed-delimited string values, but that value cannot guarantee that each line corresponds to exactly one complete file name, because filenames can contain newlines.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for some additional information.

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `shuf` and Bash 4.3+:

```sh
readarray -d '' files < <(shuf --zero-terminated --echo f*)
./script "${files[@]}"
```

where the `--zero-terminated` can handle any filenames, and `readarray` also uses the null byte as the delimiter.

With older Bash where `readarray` doesn't support the `-d` option:

```sh
while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
    files+=("$f")
done < <(shuf --zero-terminated --echo f*)
./script "${files[@]}"
```

---

In extreme cases with many files, this might run into command line length limitations; in that case,

```sh
shuf --zero-terminated --echo f*
```

could be replaced by

```sh
printf '%s\0' f* | shuf --zero-terminated
```

<sub>Hat tip to [Socowi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6770384/socowi) for pointing out `--echo`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It's very difficult to get this completely correct.  A simple attempt would be to use `%q` specifier to `printf`, but I believe that is a bashism.  You still need to use `eval`, though. eg:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/sh

for x; do echo $((i++)): "$x"; done
$ ./a.sh *
0: a.sh
1: name
with
newlines
2: name with spaces
$ eval ./a.sh $(printf "%q " *)
0: a.sh
1: name
with
newlines
2: name with spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Maybe you should explain the *real* problem, someone might have a much better solution.

Nonetheless, working with what you posted, I'd say read [this page on why you shouldn't try to parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) as it has relevant points; then I suggest an array.

```
lst=(f*)
./script "${lst[@]}"
```

This will still fail if you reparse it as the output of a subshell, though -

```
./script  $( echo "${lst[@]}" )  #  still  fails same way
./script "$( echo "${lst[@]}" )" # *still* fails same way
```

Thinking about how we could make it work...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs`:

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  0 2021-08-13 00:23 '  file  1'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  0 2021-08-13 00:23 '  file  2'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  0 2021-08-13 00:23 '  file  3'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  0 2021-08-13 00:23 '  file  4'
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35 2021-08-13 00:25  script
$ ./script *file*
  file  1
  file  2
  file  3
  file  4
$ ls *file* | shuf | xargs -d '\n' ./script
  file  4
  file  2
  file  1
  file  3
```

If your `xargs` does not support `-d`:

```
$ ls *file* | shuf | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 ./script
  file  3
  file  1
  file  4
  file  2
```